# Illegal modifier for parameter count; only final is permitted

Tags: java

I new to Java and I have a problem, When i try making a public/private variable
EXAMPLE:
    `private int varName;`
Eclipse gives me an error:
    `Illegal modifier for parameter count; only final is permitted`

Comment: Can you  please show the code ? otherwise you'll end up with some random guesses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Local variables and parameters cannot have `public` or `private` modifier. You can only give `final` to them. Not even `static` can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot apply access-level modifiers on method parameters. They are acceptable only on class members. Furthermore, that wouldn't make any sense because a parameter cannot possibly be accessed outside of the method scope.

Comment: @user3421750 Think of it. What good will those modifiers do there? You can't access local variables outside a method anyways.

Comment: There is no syntax to even *try* to refer to a method parameter from anywhere outside that method. Maybe you should explain what you are after instead of asking about your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens generally whenever we try to access variable which is local and we try to access it in Anonymous class methods like below:

```
JButton button=new JButton();
        int a=5;
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(""+a);//Compiler Error:Cannot refer to a non-final variable a inside an inner class defined in a different method
            }
        });
```

so here the variable "a" need to be final or Class variable to be accessed inside the Anonymous class method.